# Modify WebView HTML with JS dependencies in Android

Tags: android, html

**To do:**
I want to modify the HTML file's content and put my own values in it. The HTML file has JS dependencies (saved locally to reduce network usage).

**Already tried:**
I opened the file as a String and performed necessary String operations to put my values in place, the I pulled the String to WebView using loadData, it doesn't work as the internally referenced JS files cant be found.
I can't seem to save the file after editing due to android's regulations.

**What to do?**

I am looking to put [this](http://ugomeda.github.io/d3-liquid-fill-gauge/) d3js gauge in the Android app.
Any suggestion on how to efficiently pull this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What worked**

1. Read the HTML file with InputStreamReader as a string
2. Perform String operations to modify the contents for the desirable outcome
3. Now load the String in the WebView as:
   `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "utf-8",
   null);`

Where `str` is the HTML file's modified String.

This way we can load the HTML file from `assets`, modify it as per our needs, use local resources in the HTML code to speed up operations.